# Spring Boot - One to Many Relationship - Error with 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-boot, one-to-many

I created a Spring Boot project with Postgres DB. It has an one to many relation with Project and Taxonomy which means one project can have only one Taxonomy, but a Taxonomy can have multiple projects. It works if i do not specify this relationship, but after introducing the relationship, it throughs an exception.

**models**

**Taxonomy.java**

```
package ebi.uk.eva.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import ebi.uk.eva.model.Project;

@Entity
@Table(name = "taxonomy")
public class Taxonomy {

@Id 
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "taxonomy_common_name")
@NotNull
private String commonName;

private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();

public Taxonomy() {

}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCommonName() {
    return commonName;
}

public void setCommonName(String commonName) {
    this.commonName = commonName;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "taxonomy", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}
}
```

**Project.java**

```
package ebi.uk.eva.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {

@Id 
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String id;

@Column(name = "title")
@NotNull
private String title;

private Taxonomy taxomony;

public Project() {

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "taxonomy_id")
public Taxonomy getTaxomony() {
    return taxomony;
}

public void setTaxomony(Taxonomy taxomony) {
    this.taxomony = taxomony;
}
}
```

**ProjectRepository.Java**

```
package ebi.uk.eva.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ebi.uk.eva.model.Project;

@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, String>{
}
```

**Appication.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/evadb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=****
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

**Application.java (main)**

```
package ebi.uk.eva;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EvaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EvaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ebi.uk.eva</groupId>
<artifactId>EBIProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>EBIProject</name>
<description>EBI test project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**Error**

```
017-11-21 06:52:17.899  INFO 75167 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-21 06:52:17.913 ERROR 75167 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at ebi.uk.eva.EvaApplication.main(EvaApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ebi.uk.eva.model.Taxonomy, at table: project, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(taxomony)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:455) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:451) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.12.Final.jar:5.2.12.Final]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your Project class. `mappedBy` is set to "taxonomy" and the Project field is named "taxomony"

`Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ebi.uk.eva.model.Taxonomy, at table: project, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(taxomony)]`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "taxonomy")
public class Taxonomy {
///
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "taxonomy", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}
 ///
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {

  ///

  private Taxonomy taxomony;
  ///

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "taxonomy_id")
  public Taxonomy getTaxomony() {
      return taxomony;
  }

  public void setTaxomony(Taxonomy taxomony) {
      this.taxomony = taxomony;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Although I corrected the typo (and getters and setters), I get the same issue